# How to use when statement in ansible

Tags: ansible

Can anyone check the script? I don't know why the "when" statement failed.

> ok: [labvMME01] => {
>       "msg": [
>           "Wait!",
>           "Exported result: /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/jackl/ConfigFile_from_export"
>       ]
>   }*******************************************************************
>   fatal: [labvMME01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'path' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to

```
- name: mme command
  shell: gsh export_config_active
  register: command_result

- name: check result
  debug: msg="{{command_result.stdout_lines}}"

- name: get the path of the config file
  set_fact: path="{{command_result.stdout_lines}}"
  when: '"Exported" in command_result.stdout_lines'
- debug: msg="{{path}}"
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: when: '"Exported" in command_result.stdout_lines', these command can not find the matched string. you can see the stdout_lines contain  [ "Wait!", "Exported result: /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/jackl/ConfigFile_from_export" ]

Comment: output of command_result also please

Comment: TASK [check result] ************************************************************
ok: [labvMME01] => {
    "msg": [
        "Wait!",
        "Exported result: /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/jackl/ConfigFile_from_export"
    ]
}

Comment: @jackliu when trying to help you people are looking for the most accurate info in your question, not in comments. Please add the supplementary info directly in your question by editing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as below.

```
- name: get the path of the config file
  set_fact: path="{{command_result.stdout}}"
  when: '"Exported" in command_result.stdout'
```

Comment: It works this time. But I would like to know why it didn't work with stdout_lines

Comment: stdout - comparision is done with a string. but stdout_lines provides a list of strings so we cannot compare.

Comment: The following is the output of command_result.stdout.TASK [check result] ************************************************************
ok: [labvMME01] => {
    "msg": "Wait!\nExported result: /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/jackl/ConfigFile_from_export"

Comment: yes, stdout has value in " " , which means it is a string,but stdout_lines has value in [" "], which means it is a list, hence it doesnt work

Comment: Thank you for your kindly support